rabbitMQ is not connected and rabbitMQ url is not working for windows os
Getting error in rabbbitmq command, error: Could not bind distribution port 25672 it is in use by another node and also http://localhost:15672 is not opened in browser
I need connect with rabbitMQ server and send message and get response. rabbitMQ url is not working in browser.
